# Equidistribution of distances of integer points to a circle

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-probability, equidistribution

I have noticed in the following graph that the euclidean distance
between points $k \in\mathbb{Z}^2\cap C_7^1$ ($C_7^1:={}$Circle with radius 7 and shell with thickness 1) and the nearest point on the inner circle is quite random.
[image: Illustration of distance phenomenon]

I did some further investigations in R and figured out that the distances for large radii are seemingly uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$.

[image: Graph of near-uniform distribution]

This leads to the following question. Let $C_r^1$ be the centered circle with radius r and shell with thickness 1 (as in figure 1). We denote by $A_r$ the set $\{k\in \mathbb{Z}^2:k\in C_r^1 \cap \mathbb{Z}^2\}$.

We replace each element in the set $A_r$ with the corresponding euclidean distance to the nearest point on the centered circle with radius r.

My conjecture is that for every closed subinterval $[a,b]$ in $[0,1]$ we have

$$
\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\operatorname{card}(A_r\cap [a,b])}{\operatorname{card}(A_r)}=b-a.
$$

Does anyone have an idea how to prove this conjecture?

Comment: Shorter version: For lattice points at distances from the origin between $r$ and $r+1$, are those distances approximately uniformly distributed in that range?

Comment: After a post receives an answer (and especially after you accept it!), it’s inappropriate to add further questions in the post — it would be appropriate instead to put the new question in some short new self-contained post, and link to this one for context.

Comment: Matt F is unhappy with the modified question, and I am unhappy with the modified question, and I'm unhappy with your suggestion to put Anthony Quas on the spot. It's just common courtesy not to change a question after another user has posted an answer. Please, Hyy, do the right thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. What you are looking for follows from the known error bounds in the [Gauss Circle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem). In particular, in the notation of that Wiki article, $\text{card}(A_r\cap [a,b])=N(r+b)-N(r+a^-)$, while $\text{card}(A_r)=N(r+1)-N(r^-)$. From the upper bounds on the error due to Huxley mentioned in the Wiki article, $N(r+b)-N(r+a^-)=\pi((r+b)^2-(r+a^-)^2)+O(r^{131/208})$, while $N(r+1)-N(r^-)=\pi((r+1)^2-r^2)+O(r^{131/208})$.

Hence the ratio is
$$\frac{2(b-a)r+O(r^{131/208})}{2r+O(r^{131/208})}=b-a+O(r^{-77/208}).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me how to arrive at the term $O(r^{-\frac{-77}{208}})$?

Comment: Divide through top and bottom by $r$.